# Opensource: Enterprise Service Bus for services : WCF & Web API

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api, soa, esb

Investigating various open source ESB technologies to implement with in SOA.

Below are few ESB technologies available come across:-

1. NserviceBus
2. ServiceStack
3. phonenix http://pservicebus.codeplex.com/
4. masstransit
5. RabbitMQ
6. Rockbus.codeplex.com

Would like to utilise open source technology. Would appreciate sharing the experience with resources in implementing a open source ESB. In the investigation there seems to be no/few resources to get started, with regard to open source ESB.

## Help appreciated

---

1. Walk through guide to implement open source ESB for Microsoft developed technologies.

Comment: is it 'open source' or 'free for commercial purposes'?

Comment: open source (free) for research organisation, not for commercial purpose.

Comment: You might also want to look at WSO2 ESB which is open source and comes with Apache license - http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/. Also, if you're looking at general functionality of a ESB then the sample catalog might be helpful to identify what type of things can be done using it. Listed here - http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Samples. Full disclosure - I work for WSO2 :-)

Comment: Another good resource is this website: http://www.eaipatterns.com/ You might also want to consider buying the book.

Answer (score 0):

I had a good experience with Apache NMS (.NET Messaging API).

NMS Provider is a .NET Assembly that provides an implementation of the NMS API that provides connectivity with a particular Messaging Service or an implementation of a standard Messaging Protocol

To implement ESB using WCF is not a good Idea.

**Apache ActiveMQ, Even it support Windows communication foundation.** 
Reference  : http://activemq.apache.org/nms/apachenmswcf.html